# How to conflate the value based on sharing ID using sql or python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, sqlite

So, I have four important fields: `RIVER_ID`, `Feature_ID`, `Name` and `Name count`. A `RIVER_ID` represents one river and it usually contains several features with their unique `Feature_IDs`. Let's say that river `Danube` has `RIVER_ID` of **12** and there are **20** features with their differing `Feature_IDs`. **10** of these features are named and **10** are unnamed, but also from the ten named ones **1** is named `Sava` and the rest are named `Danube` whilst the rest are NULL values. I want to conflate the Name that occurs the most of the times for a specific ID based on `RIVER_ID`. I have created a simple query that selects the only named ones but don't really know how to conflate these values to the NULL ones.

```
SELECT RIVER_ID, Name, 
Feature_ID, Name count
FROM river_names
WHERE Name! = 'NULL'
GROUP BY RIVER_ID, Name count
ORDER BY RIVER_ID, Name count;
```

I am doing this using `import sqlite3` and creating a connection in `Python3`. I have also tried using `.CSV` and looping through it, but I think `sqlite3` should be a simpler solution.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('multiple_names.sqlite')

c = conn.cursor()

# print(c.execute("SELECT RIVER_ID, value, Name count FROM river_names WHERE value != 'NULL' GROUP BY RIVER_ID, Name count ORDER BY RIVER_ID, Name count DESC"))

red = []
for row in c.execute("SELECT RIVER_ID, value, Name count FROM river_names WHERE value IS NOT 'NULL' GROUP BY RIVER_ID, Name count ORDER BY RIVER_ID, Name count DESC"):
    print(row)
    red.append(row)
```

This is what I have at the moment and it prints out a list of (RIVER_ID, Name, Name Count). I want to compare the features with the same RIVER_ID and different Names and append the name that occurs the most to all features with the same RIVER_ID including those without a name.

Comment: You can use `COALESCE(Name, '<unnamed>')` to substitute (e.g.) `<unnamed>` for NULL values, if that helps.

Comment: Also, if the column truly is named `"Name count"`, you will need to quote it in the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Name` that occurs the most for each `RIVER_ID` with aggregation and the window function `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       RIVER_ID, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY RIVER_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) most_occuring_Name
FROM river_names
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY RIVER_ID, Name
```

If you want this `Name` returned when you query the table then join the table to the above query:

```
SELECT r.RIVER_ID, t.most_occuring_Name Name, r.Feature_ID, r.[Name Count]
FROM river_names r LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           RIVER_ID, 
           FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY RIVER_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) most_occuring_Name
    FROM river_names
    WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY RIVER_ID, Name 
) t ON t.RIVER_ID = r.RIVER_ID
```